# How to avoid black option in angular ejs select option tag?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, ejs, two-way-binding

Hello I am using  and ng-repeat to dynamically load up the options.

```
            <select ng-init="NewPeriod[webhosting.index] || NewPeriod[webhosting.index]" style="font-size: 13px;" class="form-control" name="period" ng-model="NewPeriod[webhosting.index]" ng-change="updateHPeriod(webhosting.index)">
                                            <option ng-repeat="period2 in Periods[webhosting.key] | orderBy: 'billingPeriod'" ng-selected="period2.billingPeriod == webhosting.period" autocomplete="off" value="{{period2.billingPeriod}}" ng-value="{{period2.billingPeriod}}" ng-if="period2.billingPeriod == 1">{{period2.billingPeriod}} month for ${{period2.amount.toFixed(2)}}
                                            </option>
                                            <option ng-repeat="period2 in Periods[webhosting.key] | orderBy: 'billingPeriod'" ng-selected="period2.billingPeriod == webhosting.period" autocomplete="off" value="{{period2.billingPeriod}}" ng-value="{{period2.billingPeriod}}" ng-if="period2.billingPeriod != 1">{{period2.billingPeriod}} months for ${{period2.amount.toFixed(2)}}
                                            </option>
                                        </select>
```

Here is my attempt to fix (Tried initializing it but no success)

```
            <select  ng-init="NewPeriod[webhosting.index] || NewPeriod[webhosting.index] || Periods[webhosting.key][0] " style="font-size: 13px;" class="form-control" name="period" ng-model="NewPeriod[webhosting.index]" ng-change="updateHPeriod(webhosting.index)">
                                            <option ng-repeat="period2 in Periods[webhosting.key] | orderBy: 'billingPeriod'" ng-selected="period2.billingPeriod == webhosting.period" autocomplete="off" value="{{period2.billingPeriod}}" ng-value="{{period2.billingPeriod}}" ng-if="period2.billingPeriod == 1">{{period2.billingPeriod}} month for ${{period2.amount.toFixed(2)}}
                                            </option>
                                            <option ng-repeat="period2 in Periods[webhosting.key] | orderBy: 'billingPeriod'" ng-selected="period2.billingPeriod == webhosting.period" autocomplete="off" value="{{period2.billingPeriod}}" ng-value="{{period2.billingPeriod}}" ng-if="period2.billingPeriod != 1">{{period2.billingPeriod}} months for ${{period2.amount.toFixed(2)}}
                                            </option>
                                        </select>
```

I see blank value, even though there is no blank value and default is set to blank. How can I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66319057/remove-blank-option-from-angularjs-dropdown does this help?

Comment: Not really, can you please enlighten more based on above scenario? I am bit confused.

Comment: most of the time the blank option is there because the value reference by ngmodel is not in the list of options. sometimes even if it's the same value but different reference. so i would try assign the ngmodel if this is the case

Answer (score 0):

To change the presentation/properties of the blank field, you must alter the option with value "" (blank). Add the following line above your options:

```
<option value="" ng-if="false"></option>
```

ng-if="false" prevents it from showing.

Or, if you would like it to say "Select One..." etc. you can keep it and change the text:

```
<option value="" selected> Select One...</option>
```

Adding the selected option makes it the default.

Comment: unfortunately, that didnt fix and not making any difference.

Comment: would you be able to use ng-options instead of doing ng-repeat with the list of options (and then adding the option field for the blank value)? that might be a workaround